# How to get different values from 2 data frame

Tags: r

I wanted to compare values in 2 columns from 2 data frame

```
data_id1 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```

And

```
data_id2 <- c(2, 4)
```

So I wanted new column that EXCLUDE data id2

New data should include only 1,3,5,6

Comment: `data_id1[-data_id2]`

Comment: @Charles just for the record, you are dealing with vectors, not data.frames

Comment: @Jilber actually it did not work for me. Is there other options to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `setdiff`...

```
setdiff(data_id1,data_id2)
[1] 1 3 5 6
```

Comment: actually it did not work for me. Is there other options to do this ?